# in R replace value with most common value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with time and a transport mode. There are some values, that are classified in a walking part as "unknown" or false classified as an other transport mode, for example "car"

Here is the structure

```
travel <- structure(list(time = structure(1:19, .Label = c("16:20:20", 
"16:20:21", "16:20:22", "16:20:23", "16:20:24", "16:20:25", "16:20:26", 
"16:20:27", "16:20:28", "16:20:29", "16:20:30", "16:20:31", "16:20:32", 
"16:20:33", "16:20:34", "16:20:35", "16:20:36", "16:20:37", "16:20:38"
), class = "factor"), mode = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("car", 
"bus stop", "walk"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Here you can see the dataframe

```
    time        mode
1   16:20:20    walk
2   16:20:21    walk
3   16:20:22    walk
4   16:20:23    bus stop
5   16:20:24    bus stop
6   16:20:25    bus stop
7   16:20:26    bus stop
8   16:20:27    bus stop
9   16:20:28    walk
10  16:20:29    walk
11  16:20:30    walk
12  16:20:31    walk
13  16:20:32    walk
14  16:20:33    walk
15  16:20:34    car
16  16:20:35    car
17  16:20:36    car
18  16:20:37    car
19  16:20:38    car
```

I'd like to replace the values that are not correct. In the data example, the observations 4,5 and 7 have to be classified as "walk".

I think of a mutate function, that looks at the pre and post values ob the observations. if before and after the "unknown" values the value is the same mode (for examnple: walk) then the unknown values are classified as "walk". Also the observation 7 has somehow be classified as "walk".

thx for your help!

Comment: If car in row 7 is invalid why not car in rows 15 to19? Moreover, which are the valid values and which are invalid? Is there any criteria for deciding these?

Comment: row 7 is invalid, because it was classified wrong by my algorhtim -> the mean speed was to high for a walk - noise of the GPS. row 15 - 19 are correct, because the mean speed is (with a rolling average) to high for walk -> with geographic information it is classifed as a car ride.

Comment: criteria is, that within for example 50 rows a change from a transport mode walk to car for just 1 or 2 seconds is not realistic.

Comment: what if both sides of unknown as different and valid values?

Comment: how do you mean "both sides of unknown"?  walk walk walk unknown car ? Then it should be marked as unknown.

Comment: One more question - do you have a row for each second or for some seconds it may be missing?

Comment: Yes. There is no missing second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed your sample data a bit.

```
travel <- structure(list(time = structure(1:19, .Label = c("16:20:20", 
                                                           "16:20:21", "16:20:22", "16:20:23", "16:20:24", "16:20:25", "16:20:26", 
                                                           "16:20:27", "16:20:28", "16:20:29", "16:20:30", "16:20:31", "16:20:32", 
                                                           "16:20:33", "16:20:34", "16:20:35", "16:20:36", "16:20:37", "16:20:38"
), class = "factor"), mode = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                         3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("car", 
                                                                                                             "unknown", "walk"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         -19L))
travel

       time    mode
1  16:20:20    walk
2  16:20:21    walk
3  16:20:22    walk
4  16:20:23 unknown
5  16:20:24 unknown
6  16:20:25    walk
7  16:20:26     car
8  16:20:27    walk
9  16:20:28    walk
10 16:20:29    walk
11 16:20:30    walk
12 16:20:31    walk
13 16:20:32    walk
14 16:20:33 unknown
15 16:20:34     car
16 16:20:35     car
17 16:20:36     car
18 16:20:37     car
19 16:20:38     car
```

Now use this syntax, for a maximum of two discrepancies

```
library(data.table)
travel %>% group_by(d = rleid(mode)) %>%
  mutate(d2 = n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(mode = case_when( d2 == 1 & lag(mode) == lead(mode) ~ lag(mode),
                            d2 == 2 & first(mode[d]) == first(mode[d-1]) ~ first(mode[d-1]),
                            TRUE ~ mode)) %>%
  select(-d, -d2)

# A tibble: 19 x 2
   time     mode   
   <fct>    <fct>  
 1 16:20:20 walk   
 2 16:20:21 walk   
 3 16:20:22 walk   
 4 16:20:23 walk   
 5 16:20:24 walk   
 6 16:20:25 walk   
 7 16:20:26 walk   
 8 16:20:27 walk   
 9 16:20:28 walk   
10 16:20:29 walk   
11 16:20:30 walk   
12 16:20:31 walk   
13 16:20:32 walk   
14 16:20:33 unknown
15 16:20:34 car    
16 16:20:35 car    
17 16:20:36 car    
18 16:20:37 car    
19 16:20:38 car
```

Comment: Thx for your input and the help! I will implement the code!

Comment: Hi AnilGoyal, The code worked and I could improve the efficency! With the code I hoped, that the aan other problem is also solved. I edited the sample data in the Question. If the mode is walk than bus stop and then walk -> I have to change the mode to walk. the problem is, that the length of the bus stop is not fix. When it is walk, walk, walk, bus stop, bus stop, bus, bus bus then it is fine. Can you help me with that?

Comment: and the code works only for the mode "walk"... if the data looks like this: car, car, car, unknown, unknown, car, car. -> the code return: car, car, car, walk, walk, car, car. -> It should only return car.

Answer (score 1):

The first step could be to change the `mode` "unknown" to NA and use `zoo::na.locf` to fill in with the preceding non-NA values, if that is what you want.

Secondly, you could for example define a single occurrence of another `mode` as something you would like to replace, again using the preceding known value. You can use `rle` to find such cases.

```r
df <- read.table(text="    time        mode
1   16:20:20    walk
2   16:20:21    walk
3   16:20:22    walk
4   16:20:23    unknown
5   16:20:24    unknown
6   16:20:25    walk
7   16:20:26    car
8   16:20:27    walk
9   16:20:28    walk
10  16:20:29    walk
11  16:20:30    walk
12  16:20:31    walk
13  16:20:32    walk
14  16:20:33    walk
15  16:20:34    car
16  16:20:35    car
17  16:20:36    car
18  16:20:37    car
19  16:20:38    car
", header=T)

library(zoo)
df$mode[df$mode=="unknown"] <- NA
df$mode <- na.locf(df$mode)
rdf <- rle(df$mode)
rdf$values[which(rdf$lengths==1)] <- NA
df$mode <- na.locf(inverse.rle(rdf))
df
#>        time mode
#> 1  16:20:20 walk
#> 2  16:20:21 walk
#> 3  16:20:22 walk
#> 4  16:20:23 walk
#> 5  16:20:24 walk
#> 6  16:20:25 walk
#> 7  16:20:26 walk
#> 8  16:20:27 walk
#> 9  16:20:28 walk
#> 10 16:20:29 walk
#> 11 16:20:30 walk
#> 12 16:20:31 walk
#> 13 16:20:32 walk
#> 14 16:20:33 walk
#> 15 16:20:34  car
#> 16 16:20:35  car
#> 17 16:20:36  car
#> 18 16:20:37  car
#> 19 16:20:38  car
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Or, more succinctly, combining the two conditions upfront:

```r
library(zoo)
rdf <- rle(df$mode)
rdf$values[with(rdf, lengths==1 | values=="unknown")] <- NA
df$mode <- na.locf(inverse.rle(rdf))
```

Comment: thx for the input. In my data (over 10 mio) rows are definitely "real" NA values. Would you suggest to give the real NA values another expression?

Comment: If you want to retain them as NA, you could temporarily rename them before the `na.locf` operation and set them back to NA afterwards if you like.